# nhibernate odbc connection string

Tags: hadoop, nhibernate, odbc, connection-string

I need to connect to Hadoop Database using nHibernate. I am trying to do this using **`NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver`**. The driver that we are using is Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala.

The connection string that works if used through code is following:

```
DRIVER=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala;
          Host=<Server>;
          Port=<port>;
          Schema=<schema>;
          AuthMech=0;
          CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=0;
          TrustedCerts=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala\lib\cacerts.pem;
```

I want to keep this connection string in nHibernate configuration so have added following:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">
            NHibernate.Driver.OdbcDriver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
          DRIVER=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala;
          Host=<Server>;
          Port=<port>;
          Schema=<schema>;
          AuthMech=0;
          CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=0;
          TrustedCerts=C:\Program Files (x86)\Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala\lib\cacerts.pem;
        </property>
```

But this fails with the **Exception** :

```
Message=ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified .
```

Please note that this connection string works fine without **`nHibernate`**. Anything obvious that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the application was built for 64 bit configuration and the driver that was installed was 32 bit. Changed the configuration and build it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else; I installed the x64 bit driver and the doc says

```
Driver=Cloudera Impala ODBC Driver;
```

but the 64-Bit ODBC Administrator uses

```
Driver=Cloudera ODBC Driver for Impala;
```

once I switched to the appropriate name, it worked seamlessly